# How to use Q.Promise<string> as string?

Tags: typescript, promise, q

I have function returning string Q.Promise

```
module test {

    export function promiseString (): Q.Promise<string> {
        var deferred = Q.defer<string>();
        deferred.resolve('someMessage');
        return deferred.promise;
    }

}
```

How I can to use return value as string?

**Option #1:**

```
Q.fcall(promiseString).then(function (message: string) {
    //  compilation error about incompatible parameters     
});
```

**Option #2:**

```
Q.fcall(promiseString).then(function (promise: Q.Promise<string>) {
    console.log(typeof promise);    //  output string
    //  but i can't use promise as string further
});
```

Comment: Don't use `Q.fcall`, that's for callbacks! The second option should give a type error as well - `then` callback arguments are *never* promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the function always returns a promise (deferred or otherwise), then you don't have to call it with `Q.fcall`. Simply call:

```
promiseString().then(...)
```